# Everytime I save entity framework is leaving old data and creating new for ICollection property of a model

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Please someone guide me how can I save and update data into database without creating copy of row. Whenever I save it's create a new record instead update current one. So, my question is, is there anything wrong in model creation or relation between model
Here’s the models

```
 public class Order
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public string FromLoc { get; set; }
    public string ToLoc { get; set; }
    public Division Devision { get; set; } = Division.None;
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public OrderPriority Priority { get; set; } = OrderPriority.None;
    public bool IsSubmitted { get; set; }
    public OtherField Others { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderDetails> Details { get; set; } //Problem is here 
}
public class OrderDetails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int WHStock { get; set; }
    public int BranchStock { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

I am using fluent API for model configuration here’s the config code

```
 public class OrderConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblOrderHead");
        HasKey(k=>new { k.ID,k.Number});

        Property(p=>p.FromLoc).IsRequired();
        Property(p=>p.ToLoc).IsRequired();


        HasMany(m => m.Details);
    }
}
```

And then this is save function

```
 private async void Save()
    {
        OtherField comField = new OtherField
        {
            CreateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName,
            UpdateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName
        };

        var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
        Task<Order> taskFindOrder = new Task<Order>(()=> {
            //details
            foreach (OrderDetailsViewModel item in orderDetailsViewModelBindingSource)
            {
                OrderDetails details = new OrderDetails
                {
                    ProductCode = item.ProdCode,
                    BranchStock = item.BRStk,
                    WHStock = item.WHStk,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity

                };
                orderDetails.Add(details);
            }
            return con.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Number == txtOrderNumber.Text).Result; ;
        });
        taskFindOrder.Start();
        var find = await taskFindOrder;

        if (find != null)
        {
            //run update
            find.Details.Clear();
            find.Details = orderDetails;
            find.Others.UpdateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName;
            find.Others.UpdateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            var order = new Order
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FromLoc = frmWelcome._LocationCode,
                ToLoc="",
                Number = txtOrderNumber.Text,
                Others = comField,
                Details=orderDetails
            };
            con.Orders.Add(order);
        }
        try
        {
            var result = await con.SaveChangesAsync();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                new Msg("Successfull", "Record successfully saved.", Msg.MsgType.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                new Msg("Failed!", "Record failed to save into database.", Msg.MsgType.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Msg("Error!", ex.Message, Msg.MsgType.Error);
        }

    }
```

and when save it's ok but when it's run update

This is result after save, please see the result too

[image]

Comment: Does `OrderDetailsViewModel` class contain `ID` property (similar to `OrderDetails`)?

Comment: No it's not here's the class

<pre>
public class OrderDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string ProdCode { get; set; }
        public string RefNo { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }
        public int WHStk { get; set; }
        public int BRStk { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }
</pre> @Ivan Stoev

Comment: Then there is no way to identify existing `OrderDetails` record to be updated (except you have some secondary uniqueness, in which case you have to write the logic yourself). In general EF has no other choice than adding new order details records. And it leaves the old records with null FKs because the relationship is *optional* by default. If you want the old records to be deleted, then make the relationship *required* (`HasMany(m => m.Details).WithRequired();`). But make sure first to delete all records from the table having `NULL` FK.

Comment: I did that too. But after that it's giving some another error...

**System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.**

Comment: `UpdateException: A relationship from the 'Order_Details' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Order_Details_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.`

Comment: Ok, here is what you can do. First eager load the existing details here `con.Orders.Include(x => x.Details).FirstOrDefaultAsync(...)`. Then instead of `find.Details.Clear();` delete them from the `DbSet` - `con.OrderDetails.RemoveRange(find.Details);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is this is correct way or not but for time being it resolve the issue. Anyone have any idea about it please do share with me what I did is below

```
private async void Save()
    {
        OtherField comField = new OtherField
        {
            CreateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName,
            UpdateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName
        };

        var orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();
        Task<Order> taskFindOrder = new Task<Order>(()=> {
            //details
            foreach (OrderDetailsViewModel item in orderDetailsViewModelBindingSource)
            {
                OrderDetails details = new OrderDetails
                {
                    ProductCode = item.ProdCode,
                    BranchStock = item.BRStk,
                    WHStock = item.WHStk,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity

                };
                orderDetails.Add(details);
            }
            return con.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Number == txtOrderNumber.Text).Result; ;
        });
        taskFindOrder.Start();
        var find = await taskFindOrder;

        if (find != null)
        {
            //run update
            var del = find.Details; //get all previous details
            con.OrderDetails.RemoveRange(del); //addedd this line here to delete
            find.Details = orderDetails; //assign the new value
            find.Others.UpdateBy = frmWelcome._User.UserName;
            find.Others.UpdateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            var order = new Order
            {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FromLoc = frmWelcome._LocationCode,
                ToLoc="",
                Number = txtOrderNumber.Text,
                Others = comField,
                Details=orderDetails
            };
            con.Orders.Add(order);
        }
        try
        {
            var result = await con.SaveChangesAsync();
            if (result != 0)
            {
                new Msg("Successfull", "Record successfully saved.", Msg.MsgType.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                new Msg("Failed!", "Record failed to save into database.", Msg.MsgType.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Msg("Error!", ex.Message, Msg.MsgType.Error);
        }

    }
```

It's working but I am still not satisfied with this approach there's must be some automate approach by Entity Framework